# What should I do if I get HiverServerException

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hadoop as well as hive. I tried to command hive, but it gave me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
org/apache/hadoop/hive/service/HiveServerException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)>>
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServerException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 3 more
```

I have the following lines of code in .profile shell file

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the following lines of code in .bashrc shell file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user17/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

in hive-env.sh copy this line

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export HIVE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hive/conf
```

Comment: Thanks, Kishore. But still it got me the same error. Could this error be caused because the settings of the same environment variables are defined in many shell scripts? (Sorry if this is the stupid question not even being asked :(, but I need help to understand this. )

Answer (score 0):

Do you have hive-service.jar in your hive lib?
This is the jar that has HiveServerException class and that's what can't be found as per the stack above.